# Mono switchIfEmpty emitting twice

Tags: spring-webflux

I have a scenario where i need to find a method that return a string response from external API. I have two possibilities for this response give me a valid response (with parameter 1 or parameter 2) or if both responses are not valid, return a final empty publisher to chain.

```
Mono<String> checkResponse(String parameter)
```

1. Check if call checkResponse(parameter1) is acceptable, ignore second call (switchIfEmpty) and continue chain, or
2. Check if call checkResponse(parameter2) is acceptable and continue chain, or
3. return Mono.Empty() and discard chain

Actually i have

```
checkResponse(stringArg1)
        .switchIfEmpty(checkResponse(stringArg2))
        .flatMapMany ...
        .flatMap ...
```

method

```
public Mono<String> checkResponse(String s)
return webClient.post()
                    .uri(URI)
                    .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(s))
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(String.class)
```

But switchIfEmpty is always executing.

Regards,

Comment: what do you mean by "always executing"? In both cases when there is body and in case when there's no body? Have you checked that? And if you have, how actually?

Comment: I do a mapNotNull and check if string node response is empty ir not. If non empy return a string, otherwise return null.

Comment: I mean that when result is non null the method is called/subscrive twice and not ignore (skip) switchIfEmpty method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that it's actually emitting twice?

There are two aspects of Project Reactor that is important to understand:

1. On Assembly
2. On Subscription

This code:

```java
checkResponse(stringArg1)
        .switchIfEmpty(checkResponse(stringArg2));
```

will *assemble* the `Mono`s for *both* `checkResponse` calls.

In essence, the `checkResponse`-method *is called twice* - however only the `Mono` returned from the *first* `checkResponse`-call will be *subscribed* to as long as it emits an item.

You can verify this behaviour with this:

```java
checkResponse(stringArg1)
        .doOnSubscribe(s -> System.out.println("First checkResponse subscription"))
        .switchIfEmpty(checkResponse(stringArg2)
            .doOnSubscribe(s -> System.out.println("Second checkResponse subscription"))
        );
```

Something that's very typical of reactive code is that top-level code within a method that returns a `Mono`/`Flux` usually executes at *assembly time* while all the lambdas passed to their various operators such as `map`/`flatMap`/`concatMap`/etc execute at *subscription time*.
To illustrate:

```java
public Mono<String> getName(int id) {
    // Assembly time
    System.out.println("This executes at assembly time");

    return userRepo.get(id)
        .map(user -> {
            // Subscription time
            System.out.println("This executes at subscription time");

            return user.name;
        });
}
```

---

If assembling the `Mono` might be expensive while it may never be subscribed to like in your case here, you can defer assembly until subscription-time using [`Mono.defer`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#defer-java.util.function.Supplier-):

```java
checkResponse(stringArg1)
        .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> checkResponse(stringArg2)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there's difference between assembly time and subscription time.

**Assembly** time is when you create your pipeline by building the reactive chain.

**Subscription** time is when the execution triggered and the data starts to flow. You should consider using callbacks and lambdas since they are **lazily**  evaluated.

So your `checkResponse()` method called "twice" on **assembly** time, because it is not a lambda, but just a regular method. And it returns **Mono**

You can use `Mono.defer(() -> checkResponse())` and delay the execution and assembling inner mono until you subscribed.